# Number With Decimal Counter That Continued On Windows Refresh Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this question been asked before, but i'm not lucky enough to find the solution I want.
Anyone can help improve this script to display 2 digit decimal, and count from the decimal.

```js
var counter = 22414768;
if (typeof(localStorage.getItem('counts')) != 'object') {
  counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counts'));
}
setInterval(function() {
  $(".counter").html(counter);
  ++counter;
  localStorage.setItem('counts', counter);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter"></div>
```

the number counter is already stored and continued on refresh but i want to make it display number with separator and also 2 digit decimal like 224,147.68, and it increment is on the last decimal digit.

NB: also, is it possible to make the base number decrease a random value on time interval? hoping for a help

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 234567945;
var newx = (x/100);
var newx = newx.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Output:-

```
"2,345,679.45"
```

Comment: try your code, it works..but after refresh the number won't show up